# How to fix strange character display

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea

since the update to 2019.2.1 IntelliJ shows some strange characters:
e.g. this is how the text `I18_TEST` is displayed in a `.ts` (typescript) file:
[image]

It seems that this affects `export const` definitions only (e.g. in file `test.ts`):

```
export const I18_TEST = 'i18 test';
```

I guess that this is a new feature and it probably makes sense to replace the underscores with the more readable dot, but the replacement for `18` is bad.

How can we fix this?

- Ideally I just want the numbers to be fixed
- or as a workaround completely deactivate this feature

More info:

- here is the [IntelliJ startup log](https://gist.github.com/tmtron/e0f1ec018d8952b01e994c9e7ae8df11)

Comment: Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and sample file example?

Comment: @y.bedrov sure: I've updated the question

Comment: Please try to temporarily disable custom plugins: Loaded custom plugins: .env files support (0.8), Active Intellij Tab Highlighter (1.4.0), BashSupport (1.7.12.192), Emmet Everywhere (1.2.5), File Watchers (192.6262.9), GitLab Projects (2.0.1), Ideolog (192.0.12.0), Ini (192.6262.16), LiveEdit (192.6262.9), PowerShell (2.0.2), Prettier (192.5728.12), Run Configuration as Action (1.3), YAML/Ansible support (0.9.5), nginx Support (0.1.6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the font: in `Settings` - `Editor` - `Color Scheme` - `Color Scheme Font`:

- The Scheme was `Darcula` (as expected)
- But the Font was set to `Source Code Pro Semibold`

Fix was to reset this to the Font `Consolas`.

Note: also other `Source Code Pro` variants work: e.g. `Source Code Pro Medium` is okay